# Is there an explanation for what all of the DLCs add in with the Talisman Digital Edition?

Tags: extras

In short I bought the Talisman Digital Edition earlier in the week (oddly reminisced about the game that I hadn't played for 30 years in the morning bought it and the starter pack in the evening). Have now bought the Season Pass because of a spot Steam Sale.

I added all the DLC in but found myself a bit lost in terms of what was doing what (e.g. the Dragons and Dark amd Light Fate tokens totally threw me).

Have started another game just adding in the base game, Sacred Pool, Frostmarch, City, Dungeon and Reaper expansions & it seems a balanced kind of game.

Is there a preferred amount of DLC to add in (or a preferred set of what to add?) and is there any explanation for what they add to the game (e.g. the Dragon tokens have totally thrown me)?

Thanks in advance for any advice or suggestions.

Comment: Hi there. [rpg.se] is about more traditional tabletop RPGs, generally - I think this question probably belongs on [gaming.se] (as it's a videogame) or [boardgames.se] (as it's based on the boardgame).

Comment: Thanks. My bad. Tried Arquade and got a slightly meh response and a downvotes. Then coin flipped between here and boardgames over what would be more suitable. Guess I guessed wrong. Thanks for posting though to point it out.

Comment: no worries. Sorry Arqade was less than helpful for you.

Comment: My fault as I can see the question has the potential for being interpreted as subjective.